Electric field in power transistors
I had a question about power transistors, why are small fields used in power transistors?
I think this question could be because the voltage is high, but mostly in terms of the transistor structure I am considering, whether it is BJT or MOS.
I found an example of this issue that confused me:
Electric Field in Power Transistors:

Assume a power transistor with a collector-emitter voltage  \$V_{CE}\$ of 100 V and a drift region length \$L_\text{drift}\$ of 10 µm.

\begin{equation}
  E_d = \frac{V_{drift}}{L_{drift}} = \frac{100 \, \text{V}}{10 \times 10^{-6} \, \text{m}} = 10^7 \, \text{V/m}
\end{equation}

Such high electric fields require careful design to avoid breakdown and ensure reliability.

Electric Field in Low Voltage Transistors:

Assume a low voltage transistor with a base-collector voltage V_BC of 5V and a depletion region width W_BC of 0.5 µm.

\begin{equation}
  E_{BC} = \frac{V_{BC}}{W_{BC}} = \frac{5V}{0.5 \times 10^{-6}\text{m}} = 10^7 \, \text{V/m}
\end{equation}

Even though the field magnitude can be high locally, the overall voltage and power handling are much lower than power transistors.

I was really confused in this situation, that with a simple glance, you can say "Lower voltage means more field", but I had a problem with this example, but my main purpose in raising this question is, how does power behave in the structure of the transistor?

The ultimate limit on how much voltage a transistor can withstand is closely related to the electric field. High-voltage devices will be designed to hit the same maximum field as low-voltage devices (as the limit is mostly imposed by the semiconductor in use, which you can't trivially change), but since they need to work at higher voltages, the field needs to be spread out over a longer distance. So high-voltage devices are designed with a longer drift region.
